# Load an external stylesheet in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt, I read all the documentation about Stylesheets and I almost know how to style my app. My files are like this :

`Project/ -> 
babel.pro resources.qrc
gui/ -> QtFiles, stylesheet.qss
app/ -> main.cpp`

My main looks like this :

```
int main(int ac, char **av) {
  MyApplication app(ac, av);
  MyWidget widget;

  QFile File(":/gui/stylesheet.qss");                                                  
  File.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
  QString StyleSheet = QLatin1String(File.readAll());

  app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet);
  widget.show();

  return app.exec();

}
```

MyApplication.hpp :

```
class MyApplication : public QApplication {

public:

  MyApplication(int argc, char **av) : QApplication(argc, av) {}
  virtual ~MyApplication() {}
  virtual bool notify(QObject *rec, QEvent *ev) {
    try {
      return QApplication::notify(rec, ev);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
      std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
      exit(0);
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

And finally MyWidget.cpp :

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
  QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

  setFixedSize(1920, 1200);
  setWindowTitle(tr("Babel"));

  _tabWidget = new QTabWidget;
  _tabWidget->addTab(new Home(), tr("Home"));
  _tabWidget->addTab(new Contact(), tr("Contact"));

  _tabWidget->resize(10, _tabWidget->height());

  mainLayout->addWidget(_tabWidget);
  setLayout(mainLayout);
}
```

I added this line in my babel.pro (which is the general .pro for the compilation) : `RESOURCES += resources.qrc`

But I have this error when running the app : `QIODevice::read: device not open`

**EDIT :**

My resources file looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>                                                                        
<RCC version="1.0">
     <qresource>
        <file>/gui/stylesheet.qss</file>
     </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Did you add you stylesheet file into the resource file?

Comment: Yes , I added <file> /gui/stylesheet.qss </file> like I read in the doc

Comment: Did you add that to the `.qrc` file maunally? If so, did you add a prefix, or does your file look like `<RCC>
        <file>/gui/stylesheet.qss</file>
</RCC>`?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall : see my edit :)

Comment: Do you refer your recourse file in the project file?

Comment: @vahancho, it's mentioned in the question that he did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path was missing the ".", so `/gui/stylesheet.qss` became `./gui/stylesheet.qss` ! And it worked as expected ..

Thank you for your time guys, a dumb mistake that I'm not going to repeat !